# How to remove global constants in front of polynomial expressions?

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I have a list of polynomials, many of them are equals up to some constants. For instance I have:

```
-(1/4) (nn[2] + nn[8]) (mm[101] - 2 nn[107]) 

 1/4 (nn[2] + nn[8]) (mm[101] - 2 nn[107])
```

Where nn[ ] and mm[ ] are the variables.
I would like to have only independent polynomials in my list. To do so, I thought to remove global constants in front of each polynomial in the list and then to use DeleteDuplicates.
But I cannot achieve the first step of removing the constants.
Do you have any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Have a look at `FactorTermsList`.

Comment: Ok thanks! it worked

Answer (score 1):

I would use `CoefficientRules` because it allows to specify the polynomial ordering as a third parameter. In the simplest form you can write:

```
p1=-(1/4) (nn[2] + nn[8]) (mm[101] - 2 nn[107]);
CoefficientRules[p1]//First//Last 
(*-1/4*)
```